# How do I connect to IBM Cognos BI in java using Login/Password?

Tags: java, cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-tm1

I have a custom LDAP server setup that is connected with TM1 Cognos BI. I can login using joe/pass  fine on cognos bi website. How do i create a connection with cognos bi using java? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to learn how to use the Cognos SDK is to study the samples. If you have Cognos 11.0/11.1, the sdk is pre-installed. For previous versions, you have to install separately. For Cognos 11+, you should study

installation_location/sdk/java/Security/Logon.java

You'll see that you need to create a credentials document in xml that has your username/password info, and pass that to the SDK.

You can consult the SDK documentation for reference, but the best thing are the samples.

Comment: I see. I will take a look if I have it. But from sounds of it It is from a file. Is it possible to do it on the fly from User input via login screen?

Comment: Your SDK app can solicit user input any way you want. That is, if your app is independent of the Cognos interface. If you're looking to integrate your app with the Cognos UI, that's a different sort of question, and you would need to give a lot more detail about what you're trying to do.

Comment: i am currently using certificate to connect to cognos tm1 through bi. I want to change it to login/password instead. thats why i setup an ldap server to connect to bi.

Comment: i checked the path but dont find the java files at all.is there a place to download it?